# Error while initializing the union of struct member in c

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, structure, unions

I have a struct like this -

```
struct ArrayAdv{
        int size;
        int length;
        union{
                struct{
                        int *A;
                } dynamic;
                struct{
                        int A[20];
                } stat;
        } item;

};
```

And I am getting error when I am trying to initialize the array -

[image: Error I am encountered with]

I am trying to initialize the array like this -

```
struct ArrayAdv arrAdv;
arrAdv.item.stat.A = {33, 2, 7, 88, 35, 90, 102, 23, 81, 97};
```

And getting the error which, I have mentioned, I want it to be initialized correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error because you're not actually *initializing*, but *assigning*, and you can't assign to an array.  An initialization happens at the time a variable is defined.

What you're looking for is:

```
struct ArrayAdv arrAdv = 
    { .item = { .stat = { .A = { 33, 2, 7, 88, 35, 90, 102, 23, 81, 97 } } } };
```

Comment: You also do `{ .item.stat.A = { ... } }`